# Kivy Button in Popup can't pass variable when calling method

Tags: python, kivy

Here is a popup:

```
class TestScreen (Screen)
    def openpopup(self)
        popup = Popup()
        button = Button(on_press=self.method("1"))
        popup.add_widget(button)
        popup.open()

     def method(self, number)
        self.label.text = number
```

When the popup is called (through a button) it gives me the error: `"  AssertionError: None is not callable "` and it only works when I remove the `("1")` from `self.method`. but I want to pass a variable from the popup so how am I supposed to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
class TestScreen (Screen)
    def openpopup(self)
        popup = Popup()
        self.button = Button(on_press=self.method, text='1')
        popup.add_widget(button)
        popup.open()

    def method(self)
        self.label.text = self.button.text
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use one of the following. Please refer to the example for details.

## Snippets

### Lambda Function

```
button = Button(text="Update Label's text", on_press=lambda number: self.method(number=1))
```

or

### Partial Function

```
from functools import partial
...
button = Button(text="Update Label's text", on_press=partial(self.method, number=1))
...
    def method(self, *args, number):
```

## Example - Using Lambda Function

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class TestScreen(Screen):
    label = ObjectProperty(None)

    def openpopup(self):
        content = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        self.popup = Popup(title="Popup", size_hint=(None, None),
                           size=(400, 400), auto_dismiss=False, content=content)
        button = Button(text="Update Label's text", on_press=lambda x: self.method(x=1))
        close_btn = Button(text="Close", on_press=self.popup.dismiss)
        content.add_widget(button)
        content.add_widget(close_btn)
        self.popup.open()

    def method(self, number):
        self.label.text = str(number)


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy Passing Arguments to Method - Using Lambda"

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<ScreenManagement>:
    TestScreen:
        name: "testscreen"

<TestScreen>:
    label: label
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: "Show Popup"
            on_release: root.openpopup()
        Label:
            id: label
            text: "Test Screen"
```

### Output - Using Lambda Function

[image]
[image]
[image]

## Example - Using Partial Function

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from functools import partial


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class TestScreen (Screen):
    label = ObjectProperty(None)

    def openpopup(self):
        content = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        self.popup = Popup(title="Popup", size_hint=(None, None),
                           size=(400, 400), auto_dismiss=False, content=content)
        button = Button(text="Update Label's text", on_press=partial(self.method, number=1))
        close_btn = Button(text="Close", on_press=self.popup.dismiss)
        content.add_widget(button)
        content.add_widget(close_btn)
        self.popup.open()

    def method(self, *args, number):
        self.label.text = str(number)


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy Passing Arguments to Method - Using Partial"

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### Output - Using Partial Function

[image]
[image]
[image]